# Multiple xcode versions in Lion OSX

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, multiple-versions

I want to install xcode 4.1 in my iMac OSX Lion. But in my iMac, I have Xcode 4.2.1. How to install iOS 4.1 but not override Xcode 4.2.1?

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: I wan't to develop app for iOS 3.1.3. Actually, I don't know if in Lion we can develop app for iOS 3.13. I just guess that Xcode 4.1 can create app for iOS 3.1.3. So I need Xcode 4.1 for develop basic 3.1.3 app and Xcode 4.2.1 for test in iOS 5 or Xcode 4.3.2 for test in iOS 5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First download and install Xcode 4.1, then go the the Mac App Store and download version 4.3.2. When installing 4.3.2 you will be prompted to delete the older version, select no. You will be able to do this because older versions of Xcode (4.1) install to /Developer whereas this newest release (4.3.2) is a .app bundle that installs to /Applications.

Comment: Yup if it's for 4.3.2. I think we can't have 4.1 and 4.2.1 in same time. Maybe in future Apple would make Xcode like 4.3.2 so we can have more than one version of Xcode in Lion. Thanks before.

Comment: I wouldn't count on future releases being any different, I'm all ready surprised it took as long as it did for Xcode to come bundled in a .app.